# Extract factor level per observation in R data_frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have `dataframe` object in R:

```
dput(data_frame("n" = seq_len(10), "g" = sample(rep(factor(c("male", "female")), 5))))

structure(list(n = 1:10, g = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("n", 
"g"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Now I want to add a 3rd column and put there g's level, where I want my levels to be `1:length(unique(g))`

I am trying to do this using:

```
df %>% mutate(l = levels(g)))
```

Without luck, please advise what I am missing here?

Here is what I want:

```
n g        l
1 male     1
2 female   2
3 male     1
4 female   2
5 male     1
..
```

Comment: One option is as `dataframe %>% mutate(l = paste(levels(g), collapse=","))` since lenghs of `levels(g)` is different than number of rows.

Comment: @steves Can you show the expected output?

Comment: But I want to "label" the levels to be simpler to read - 1, 2, 3 ...
My real factor var consists of 12+ chars for each observation.
My goal is to have this factor var and a label column that will label first factor level as 1, second as 2 ....

Comment: @markus sure please look at my previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of options:

```
# Store levels as list in new column
dataframe %>% mutate(l = list(levels(g)))

# Store levels as separate by ',' in new column
dataframe %>% mutate(l = paste(levels(g), collapse=","))

# Just a column with number
dataframe %>% mutate(l = as.integer(g))

# # A tibble: 10 x 3
#       n g          l
#   <int> <fctr> <int>
# 1     1 male       2
# 2     2 male       2
# 3     3 female     1
# 4     4 female     1
# 5     5 female     1
# 6     6 female     1
# 7     7 female     1
# 8     8 male       2
# 9     9 male       2
# 10    10 male       2
```

Suggested by @DJV

```
#
df %>% mutate(l = paste(seq_along(levels(g)), collapse=","))
```

Comment: You can do this: df %>% 
  mutate(l = paste(seq_along(levels(g)), collapse=",")). As the OP wanted it with numbers :)

Comment: @DJV thanks for the idea but it gives me a char list separated by ","'s. This is not what I need.
Please have a look in a second, I am updating my desired view in my original question.

Comment: @mkr, please have a look on my desired view in my question.

Comment: @steves in that case you can just do that: `df %>% 
  mutate(l = as.numeric(g))`

Comment: Or use `toString` `dataframe %>% mutate(l = toString(levels(g)))`